# Styling inline XML tags with XSLT

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

This is a similar question to [Style inline text along with nested tags with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991398/style-inline-text-along-with-nested-tags-with-xslt), but I can't comment to get clarification, so I will elaborate my specific scenario here.  I basically have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<book>
    <chapter>
        <para>This is some text about <place>New York</place></para>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

I am using XSLT to output XHTML from my XML file, and I want to be able to put span tags or something around the content in the place tag in the example above.  The purpose is so that I can style these segments of text with CSS.  Following the example I referenced above, I added this:

```
<xsl:template match="book/chapter/para/place">
    <span class="place">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

When I load the XML document in the browser I get the error: "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed." (the stylesheet was loading properly before I added this part)

I'm assuming I lack some basic understanding of how xsl:apply-templates should be used.  I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of figuring this out.

Thanks!

Comment: "*I added this:*" You added this to what? Show us your entire stylesheet, please, so that we can reproduce the problem.  --  P.S. Doesn't your browser's error message point to the line/column where the error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The match:

```
<xsl:template match="book/chapter/para/">
```

applies templates to all **children** of the `place` element, rather than `place` itself.

Use `select` within `apply-templates` instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="book/chapter/para/place"/>
</xsl:template>
```

> In the absence of a select attribute, the xsl:apply-templates instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes.
>
> A select attribute can be used to process nodes selected by an expression instead of processing all children. The value of the select attribute is an expression. The expression must evaluate to a node-set.

**References**

- [XSLT 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)